# Difference between explicitly setting optional properties vs. using the Partial mapped type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the following simplified class:

```
const rect = new Rectangle({
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 200,
  height: 400,
});
```

The `Rectangle` constructor takes an optional `options` object where each key is also optional.

There are two ways to write type declarations for this `options` object:

**Option 1**

Write an interface where each property is optional

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(options?: RectangleConstructorOptions)
}

interface RectangleConstructorOptions {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}
```

**Option 2**

Write an interface where keys are required, but with the constructor use the `Partial` mapped type in order to make this properties of this object optional

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(options?: Partial<RectangleConstructorOptions>)
}

interface RectangleConstructorOptions {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}
```

---

While I understand how `Partial` works, I find it hard to understand the difference between the two. **When would I use one approach over the other?** What if the options object is very large (15+ properties), would that make any difference?

Also, is **Option 2** considered a bad practice in this use case?

I say that because that means consumers of those types would also have to use `Partial` at call site if they were to use `RectangleConstructorOptions` outside of the constructor like such:

```
const options: RectangleConstructorOptions = { // ERROR!
  width: 100,
  height: 200,
}

const rect = new Rectangle(options);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both work the same in this example, but I think it is better to go with Option 1. Later, if you want to add a required parameter to the interface, you need to remove the Partial and go back to the Option 1 anyway.

I do not see any reason to use Partial in this context. It is useful to eg. create Builder Classes, that take only some of the required fields for some interface, so you can provide the rest later.

Think about Partial and other advanced types as a type decorator. You should only use them when you already have a type and you want to alter it for the sake of simplicity. In this example, you are creating the type for the first time, and it is independent of other types.

Also, to avoid having to call partial at call site in Option 2 you can always create named alias:

```
interface RectangleConstructorOptionsRequired {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

type RectangleConstructorOptions = Partial<RectangleConstructorOptionsRequired>;
```

Read more on this topic here: [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

`Partial<T>` is useful when you have a `T` already defined for some other reason. Like, say you had:

```js
interface IRectangle {
   x: number;
   y: number;
   // blah blah blah
}

class Rectangle implements IRectangle {
    constructor(opts: Partial<IRectangle>) {
        // etc. ad nauseam
    }
}
```

Because we already had the interface, we can reuse it for the parameters to the constructor. But otherwise, lacking an already-defined type as such, many people prefer to be explicit and fully type out the interface.

That said, I using `Partial<T>` directly could be useful documentation. You immediately communicate that all properties in the options argument are optional. The person using your code then doesn't have to drill down into the type information for the argument to find out.

It's a pretty small issue, though. "6 or one half dozen".